# Unable to read big json data file in pig

Tags: json, twitter, apache-pig

I am practicing on twitter data.My data is here, https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw1LIIbSl0xuQTFkMzltUkpuTlk/view

I want to extract id and text from data,I am loading as follows but data is not getting read.I have registered all required jars.

`a1 = LOAD '/user/training/my_hdfs/tweet.json' USING
com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader('-nestedLoad') AS (tw:map[]);`

`DUMP a1;`

`Input(s):
Successfully read 0 records (41027 bytes) from: "/user/training/my_hdfs/tweet.json"`

`Output(s):
Successfully stored 0 records in: "hdfs://localhost:8020/tmp/temp559014472/tmp1609007351"`

Please Help!

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Comment: Hi Sandeep thank you for reading and showing interest in my problem,actually I am not getting error but message as edited above.

Comment: please keep you json-record in only one line and try again

Comment: Hi dltu thank you! but if dataset is big as I have mentioned above in the link then how to bring every json-record in one line.Manually it will take huge time.Please elaborate with simple steps and same example of dataset which I have mentioned in link as my problem is still not solved I will be very grateful to you.